# Why there are two square brackets required inside numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am learning python, and I recently came across a module Numpy. With the help of Numpy, one can convert list to arrays and perform operations much faster. 
Let's say we create an array with following values :

```
import numpy as np
np_array=array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

So we need one square bracket if we need to store one list in the form of array. Now if I want to create a 2D array, why it should be defined like this:

```
np_array=array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
```

And not like this:

```
np_array=array([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
```

I apologize if this question is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any answer.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array function has the following form.

```
array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0)
```

If you use

```
np_array=array([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
```

The function call will result in passing [1,2,3,4,5] to *object* and [6,7,8,9,10] to *dtype*, which wont make any sense.

Comment: That was helpful! Thank you :)

Comment: One could then ask *why* `array`'s signature is not `array(*objects, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0)` and the answer would be "because it wouldn't make any sense" and that it would probably go against several conventions (and would also probably complicate `array`'s implementation)

Answer (score 2):

This actually has little to do with `numpy`. You are essentially asking what is the difference between `foo(a, b)` and `foo([a, b])`.

`arbitrary_function([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])` passes two lists as separate arguments to `arbitrary_function` (one argument is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and the second is `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`).

`arbitrary_function([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])` passes a list of lists (`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]`) to `arbitrary_function`.

Now, `numpy` creators *could* have chosen to allow 
`arbitrary_function([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])` but it would have made little to no sense to do so.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. This cleared all the doubts :)